# Why tab bar is removing when implementing KYDrawerController?

Tags: swift, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to implement `KYDrawerController` to achieve a drawer view. I am using TabBarController as a base structure. But the problem is when I am showing KYDrawerController controller the tab bar of the view controller is gone and not back by closing KYDrawerController.

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            
let mainVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
let menuVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerController")

appDel.drawerController.mainViewController = mainVC
appDel.drawerController.drawerViewController = menuVC
appDel.drawerController.screenEdgePanGestureEnabled = false

appDel.window?.rootViewController = appDel.drawerController
appDel.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
appDel.drawerController.setDrawerState(.opened, animated: true)
```

Didn't understand why the problem is raised and how will solve this problem.

Comment: Did you check with the developer of `KYDrawerController ` ?

Comment: setting the **tabbarController** to **KYDrawerController.mainViewController** should do the trick according to the developer of it.